# Sequential Programming: Better nest loops or catch "events"

Tags: cobol, sequential

This is a question for program design. There are 2 possibilities I see, where I want to know which one is better and why (aspects: **readability, performance, expendability, complexity** etc.) If you got an other one (sequential only pls no OO stuff xD) feel free to post it and explain its pros and cons

It is a simple report looping over entries from a file, doing something with them and generate a printfile (without a dedicated printer, 3rdparty software, I need to calculate the pages by myself)

**Solution NESTED LOOPS** *in pseudocode*

```
//loop over entries
perform until End-Of-File

  perform page-heading    
  //loop over pages
  perform until End-Of-File or End-Of-Page

    perform calculate-entry
    perform print-entry

  end-perform
  perform page-footer
end-perform
```

**Solution EVENT** *in pseudocode*

```
//loop over entries
perform until End-Of-File

  evaluate line-counter
    case heading-position
      perform page-heading
    case footer-position
      perform reset-line-counter
      perform page-footer
    case other
      perform calculate-entry
      perform print-entry
  end-evaluate
end-perform
```

My final program will be in **cobol**, but I occurred the same question in ABAP so feel free to argument with any sequential language.

Comment: I'm extremely tempted to down vote this simply for the dismissal of state-of-the-art technology and methodology...

Answer (score 3):

The first one (nested loops) is the more traditional way, and I prefer it, as I was a COBOL programmer last century:)  However, you should probably look at the preferred coding style in your organisation in order to decide.
If you are interested in the performance question, here is a similar question, about if vs evaluate, rather than nested loops, but there is a long and very interesting answer. [Which is better in terms of performance? "if else" or "Evaluate" statement in COBOL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22627634/8021850)